# SVG Oversized on Load

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple search icon as an *SVG* I'm using, but for some reason, when I load my webpage, it is huge despite a **24x24** lock in the *CSS* and in the styling of the *SVG* itself.

It spreads out and takes up the whole page until everything is done loading, then it snaps to the normal **24x24** size. It looks absolutely ridiculous and I know I have to be doing something wrong. Any ideas?

SVG:

```
<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <symbol id="icon-search" class="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <title>search</title>
        <circle class="st0" cx="9.3" cy="9.2" r="8.6" />
        <line class="st1" x1="15.3" y1="15.4" x2="23.3" y2="23.4" />
    </symbol>
</defs>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="searchContainer">
     <div class="search">
          <input class="image" type="image" src="images/search.svg"><input class="text" type="text" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search') { this.value = ''; }" value="Search" onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'Search'; }">
      </div><!-- /search -->
</div><!-- /searchContainer -->
```

CSS:

```
input.image{
   fill: black;
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   border: 0;
   padding-top: 9px;
   text-align: right;
}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RR0q.jpg) is what I'm Seeing on Load.

Note that the other icons are also *SVGs*, but they are done in a single file with the method I couldn't use with the input for the search.

```
<svg><use xlink></use></svg>
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this by adding the width and height attributes directly to the SVG. For example, your SVG might look something like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 225 225" width="20" height="20"> 
  <title>Search</title>
  <path fill="#fff" d="M225 202v8c-2.7 7.3-7.6 12.4-15 15h-8c-7.3-1.2-12.4-5.7-17.3-10.9-6.6-7-13.6-13.7-20.4-20.6-11.5-11.6-22.9-23.2-34.3-34.7-18 10.2-36.7 14.6-56.6 11.2-34.8-5.9-57.9-25.9-69.3-59.2C2 105.2 1.3 99 0 93V78c.3-.8.7-1.5.8-2.3C6.1 38.8 27 15 62.1 3.4 67.2 1.7 72.7 1.1 78 0h15c3.6.7 7.1 1.3 10.7 2C140 8.7 170 44.2 171.1 81.2c.5 17.2-3.3 33.3-12.5 49.2 1.3 1 3 1.9 4.2 3.2 17.1 17 34.1 34.2 51.3 51.2 5.1 4.9 9.7 9.9 10.9 17.2zM85.1 146.9c33 .5 61.5-27.3 61.9-60.4.4-33.7-26.7-61.5-60.6-62.2-33.3-.7-61.5 26.8-62.1 60.6-.6 33.3 27 61.5 60.8 62z"/>
</svg>
```

Note where it says `width="20" height="20"` specifically. That will limit the SVG size when the image loads. Then you can adjust the height and width using CSS as needed.

Comment: i tried this and it still showed large for a split second before css kicks in

Comment: @carinlynchin, would you be able to link me to the site so I can take a look?

Comment: I can't because its behind authentication login but its literally a  fraction of a second.. i just gave up on it

Comment: adding the width and height to the SVG tag worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Put the SVG IMG element inside a div and then size the div and the img appropriately...

```
<div id="logo">
  <img id="logo_img" src="assets/images/logo.svg">
</div>

  #logo {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
  }
  #logo_img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't working. I updated my initial post to include more of the situation the SVG is in but even putting a constraining DIV around it did nothing because once the CSS kicks in, the search icon is fine. This is completely on initial load - the SVG is loading before the CSS style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to identify your width and height on the html dom.
Also, try using the tags below

```
<object data="your_svg_path" width="57" height="57" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the SVG and style inline.  If you put the  tags above the  tags it will remove the giant stutter on page load.

Answer (score 0):

If you can load your svg inside an `<img>` tag then set the size of the img directly

```
 <img src="badge.svg" width="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to have the opacity of the SVG element set to 0 and then set it to 1 after loading.
 1. Add the opacity: 0; to the element or its parent in your CSS.
 2. Optionally add a transition, like transition: 0.5s opacity;
 3. Create a new class, let's say "loaded", with the opacity: 1; 
 4. In JavaScript add a line in the load event that adds the "loaded" class to the SVG element or its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Even better solution...

1. Add style="display:none;" attribute inline to img tag(s).
2. Use jQuery to .show() img once page is fully loaded.

```js
  $( window ).load(function() {
  $('.container img').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<img src="https://www.zdmdesigns.com/images/zdm-logo.svg" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer to the original question, but maybe it helps someone.

If you are using a CMS and FontAwesome as JS you maybe need to disable FA in edit mode so it does not replace the tags. Without the FA-Script loaded the  stays in the content, not the .